# импортировать карту страны в postresql с помощью nominatim

Tags: postgresql, php7

**Помогите загрузить карту OpenStreetMap Data Extracts. страны в Postgresql

```
root@cc2:/app/nominatim/build#  lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
    Release:        16.04
    Codename:       xenial
```

При загрузке выдает ошибку

```
    root@cc2:/app/nominatim/build# sudo -u nominatim -- ./utils/setup.php --osm-file /app/nominatim/data.pbf --all --threads 2 2>&1
    2021-01-13 08:00:41 == module path: /app/nominatim/build/module
    2021-01-13 08:00:41 == Create DB
    2021-01-13 08:00:41 == Setup DB
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Nominatim\DatabaseError: [500]: Failed to establish database connection:could not find driver
 thrown in /app/nominatim/Nominatim-3.6.0/lib/DB.php on line 36
```

Версия Nominatim 3.6.0
postgresql-11        11.5-1.pgdg16.0
postgis              3.1.0+dfsg-1.pg
php7.0-pgsql         7.0.33-0ubuntu0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробую угадать, что не поставили пакет `php-pgsql`

Comment: php-pgsql            2:7.4+79+ubuntu

Comment: а 7.4 откуда на почти уже EOL 16.04 убунте взялся? У вас несколько разных php стоит? Какой дефолтный для пользователя?

Comment: php-pgsql            2:7.4+79+ubuntu all             PostgreSQL module for PHP [default]

Comment: Добавлю Print screen В описание темы со списком PHP. В коментарии не влезит.

Comment: Может опробовать nominatim версии ниже?

Comment: К чему мне эта наскальная живопись? Текстом пишите. Вы так и не ответили на мои вопросы из предыдущего комментария.

Comment: наскальная не наскальная, там на скрине    php-pgsql 2:7.4+79+ubuntu указана как [default]  видимо по умолчанию для всех пользователей . На скрине так же указаны все PHP установленные, вывод команды  dpkg -l. Как узнать какой дефолтный для пользователя?  сервис запущен php7.0-fpm.

Comment: 7.4 PHP Думаю можно удалить, он все равно не работает

Comment: `php -v` от пользователя, поскольку скрипт вызываете из консоли. Да и `php -i` собственно сразу, найдите в выводе связанное с pdo.

Comment: php -v   PHP 7.2.34-9+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2021 11:14:41)
php -i
phpinfo()
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,   -связанное с pdo. Там еще много чего было все не влезит в комент

Comment: Ну? Увидели, что драйвера действительно нет? Теперь-то поставили наконец подходящий пакет?

Comment: PDO  PDO support=> enabled  PDOdriver =>..  Нужно установить pdo-mysql  что ли?

Comment: Можно по конкретней пожалуйста.

Comment: ` PDOdriver =>.. ` и ключевое как раз спрятали. Есть там pgsql? Судя по наскальной живописи и тексту ошибки - нет. Вас удивляет, что для *разных* версий php нужны *соответствующие именно им* скомпилированные библиотеки?

Comment: Супер... Большое спасибо!!! Когда вы догадались?

Comment: С первого прочтения текста ошибки.

Comment: Удаляем sudo apt remove  postgis 3.1.0  Ставим sudo apt install  postgresql-11-postgis-2.5 Заработало.  Номинатим попросил догрузить что то в каталог и пошла загрузка